# Has threading in GTK w/ Python changed in PyGObject introspection?

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I'm in the process of converting a program from PyGTK to PyGObject introspection for the first time and I've hit a roadblock with threading. I have a process that takes some time to complete, so I pop up a dialog with a progress bar on it and I use a thread to do the process and to update the progress bar. This worked fine with PyGTK but after converting to PyGObject, I get all the usual improper threading weirdness: the program hangs, but it seems to hang in different parts of the process, etc. So I get the impression that something has changed but I can't figure out what.

Here's this simple PyGTK progressbar example: http://aruiz.typepad.com/siliconisland/2006/04/threads_on_pygt.html
As presented on that page, the code works. I've converted it to PyGObject introspection and I get the same problems as in  my program: it hangs, it doesn't properly update the progress bar, etc.

```
import threading
import random, time
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
#Initializing the gtk's thread engine
Gdk.threads_init()


class FractionSetter(threading.Thread):
    """This class sets the fraction of the progressbar"""

    #Thread event, stops the thread if it is set.
    stopthread = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        """Run method, this is the code that runs while thread is alive."""

        #Importing the progressbar widget from the global scope
        global progressbar 

        #While the stopthread event isn't setted, the thread keeps going on
        while not self.stopthread.isSet() :
            # Acquiring the gtk global mutex
            Gdk.threads_enter()
            #Setting a random value for the fraction
            progressbar.set_fraction(random.random())
            # Releasing the gtk global mutex
            Gdk.threads_leave()

            #Delaying 100ms until the next iteration
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop(self):
        """Stop method, sets the event to terminate the thread's main loop"""
        self.stopthread.set()

def main_quit(obj):
    """main_quit function, it stops the thread and the gtk's main loop"""
    #Importing the fs object from the global scope
    global fs
    #Stopping the thread and the gtk's main loop
    fs.stop()
    Gtk.main_quit()

#Gui bootstrap: window and progressbar
window = Gtk.Window()
progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
window.add(progressbar)
window.show_all()
#Connecting the 'destroy' event to the main_quit function
window.connect('destroy', main_quit)

#Creating and starting the thread
fs = FractionSetter()
fs.start()

Gtk.main()
```

In the documentation for Gdk's threading capabilities, it stresses that you first must run g_thread_init(NULL) before running gdk_threads_init(). But to run that, you need to link in some extra libraries. If I try to import GLib through introspection and then I try to run GLib.thread_init(), I get the following error:

```
>>> from gi.repository import GLib
>>> GLib.thread_init(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/types.py", line 44, in function
    return info.invoke(*args)
glib.GError: Could not locate g_thread_init: `g_thread_init': /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_thread_init
```

I assume this is because the extra threading libraries weren't linked. If this is the cause of my threading problems, how can I work with GLib as if those libraries have been linked?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to wrap the call to `Gtk.main()` with `Gdk.threads_enter()` and `Gdk.threads_leave()`?  All the C code examples I've seen do so.  E.g.: http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question by poking through some Gnome programs written in Python (Gnome Sudoku, in this case, which actually has helped me a couple of times).

The trick is that you have to call `GObject.threads_init()` at the beginning of your code, not `GLib.thread_init()` as the C documentation implies.

Comment: I just want to say thanks. Man, working with this stuff is 90% Googling.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was having this exact problem and had no clue where I was going wrong. I wish PyGObject had some specific documentation instead of just "check the C docs"

Comment: A modern update to this answer: GObject.threads_init() and GLib.threads_init() are synonymous and neither are actually needed in PyGObject v3.10.2 and up. See also: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

Comment: @SimonFeltman Also, in modern GTK, one would forego the use of `Gdk.threads_enter()` and `Gdk.threads_leave()` altogether, and use calls like `idle_add(lambda: progressbar.set_fraction(random.random()))` to run all GUI code in the thread that actually runs the main loop. Anything else leads to crashes and headaches.