# Thread works only on gui events pygtk

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I am developing a multithreaded application in pygtk using quickly and stuck with threads. So i am experimenting with various possibilities and found out that my thread work only when i do something in the gui
Here is my code

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.calc,args=(treeiter))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

    def calc(self,treeiter):
        store=self.builder.get_object('liststore1')
        per=0
        while 1:
            print "Calcing and changing percent,per="+str(per)
            store.set_value(treeiter,4,str(int(per))+"%")
            per+=1
            time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying to update the value in a `liststore` by thread but it only get update when i click some button or some other gui events why is that so? why is the thread not running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK+ is thread-aware, but not *thread safe*.

If you want to use GTK+ in other threads than the main thread (the one that calls `gtk.main()`), make sure you put any GTK+ calls between a [`gtk.gdk.threads_enter()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--threads-enter) and [`gtk.gdk.threads_leave()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--threads-leave). This will acquire and release the global mutex.

Don't forget to call [`gtk.gdk.thread_init()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--threads-init). Preferably right after importing GTK.

You can find more examples [like this one](http://aruiz.typepad.com/siliconisland/2006/04/threads_on_pygt.html) by googling for "pygtk multithreading".

Comment: I am developing using quickly and in it 
`from gi.repository import Gtk`
doesn't have gtk.gdk

Comment: So you're using GTK+3? In that case I think you should just use the `Gtk` prefix, so `Gtk.threads_enter()` etc.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'threads_enter'`

Comment: It seems to have moved to `GObject`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943098/has-threading-in-gtk-w-python-changed-in-pygobject-introspection).

Comment: GObject.timeout_add helped